# Color the postal code area in google maps api?

Tags: api, google-maps, area, postal

I want to show each postal code differently by having border around it and color inside its area.
I am using google maps api service in js.

Comment: hey, can anyone answer it quickly asap?

Comment: hii did you find any solution for this question.actually i am also facing problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808191/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-particular-area-on-google-map-api-v2-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Google API does not provide a feature to directly have a boundary around any kind of locality be it postal code or city. So you will have to manually get the *lat lng array* denoting the region boundary from some third party and plot the *polyline*.
The below links might be helpful.

[Google map divided in regions with color and in subregions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455917/google-map-divided-in-regions-with-color-and-in-subregions)

[google maps v3 - highlight states or regions of states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734875/google-maps-v3-highlight-states-or-regions-of-states)

[how to add or show zip code boundary Google maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051149/how-to-add-or-show-zip-code-boundary-google-maps-v3)

http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-show-the-boundaries-of-postcodes-on-google-maps

http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-get-boundaries-of-neighborhoods-in-Google-maps-api