# how to cover an area of a city in google map V2 [Android]

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

i am working on an app using google map API version 2. i want to do something like this. i want to cover-up an area using a line like below image [image]

how do i do that ?. can anyone give me some idea how to do that in android application.

thank you

Comment: I think you have to find 4-6 coordinate which cover this area and add this coordinate to your map bound.

Comment: @Haresh can you explain it further ? what is map bound ? how it works..?

Comment: Please check : http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808191/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-particular-area-on-google-map-api-v2-in-android

Answer (score 0):

What you will want is to get multiple coordinates on the map and create a Polygon out of them.

Here's a snippet you can use to get the coordinates and preview a 5 point Polygon.

```
private PolygonOptions mPolygon = new PolygonOptions();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            mPolygon.add(latLng);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(latLng.toString())
            ).showInfoWindow();

            if (mPolygon.getPoints().size() == 5) {
                mPolygon.fillColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                mMap.addPolygon(mPolygon);
            }
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

*Note:* points have to be added clockwise or counter-clockwise, zigzags won't work.